# Live Agent: Custom Style for liveAgent:clientChatLog

Tags: liveagent, stylesheets

liveAgent:clientChatLog is the VF tag which is used to display the chat transcript to a visitor.  There seems to be no way of applying any kind of style to the text in this window, nor to apply custom colors/fonts, etc to either the name of the agent, or to the text the agent typed.  Is there a way of doing this, or do we just have to use the default stylesheet?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Each chat message from the client or the operator will either have the CSS Class "client" or "operator".  So you can add CSS Styles to those CSS Classes to get the desired results.  It would look like the following.

.client {
    background: blue;
    color: white; 
}

.operator {
    background: green;
    color: white; 
}

There is a CSS Class for "name" too.

Comment: Thanks Patriot, worked a treat!  To change the name colors, I did this:

.client span.name { color: green; }

.operator span.name {color: blue; }